# Marklogic|NodeJS API - Query on attribute of a field

Tags: node.js, marklogic, nosql

I have a json structure something like

```
{
   foo:"bar",
   keyPhrases:[
      {key: "random thing", value: 5},
      {key: "another random", value: 3}
   ]
}
```

How can i do a word query on keyPhrases.key ?
I tried

`qb.word('keyPhrases.key', 'random')`

or

```
qb.word(qb.property('keyPhrases.key'), 'random')
```

and it does not work. Any ideas? I know this is possible with a QBE but for the Marklogic NodeJS API you can`t specify a collection, and I need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [qb.scope()](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#scope).

```
var ml = require('marklogic');
var conn = require('./config.js').connection;
var db = ml.createDatabaseClient(conn);
var qb = ml.queryBuilder;

db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.collection('test'),
    qb.scope(qb.property('keyPhrases'), qb.word('key', 'random'))
  )
  .withOptions({metrics: true})
).result()
.then(function(docs) {
  console.log('This search found: ' + JSON.stringify(docs[1]));
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('something went wrong: ' + error);
});
```

Alternatively, you could build a path-based field and query on that.

Comment: What if we have further nested properties

Comment: @dalvir the second parameter to `qb.scope` is a query, which can itself be a `qb.scope`. You can nest these as much as you want (but note that you'll need the positions indexes turned on). See https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery for more info.

Comment: I tried that but it failed if inner object have same key, It will give false result.

Comment: @dalvir an alternative is to configure a path-based field in the database. That will allow you to target a specific path. See https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#chapter.