# Marklogic 8 Node.js API - How can I scope a search on a property child of root?

Tags: node.js, marklogic, marklogic-8

[updated 17:15 on 28/09]

I'm manipulating json data of type:

```
[
 {
 "id": 1,
 "title": "Sun",
 "seeAlso": [
    {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Rain"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Cloud"
    }
 ]
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "title": "Rain",
 "seeAlso": [
    {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Cloud"
    }
 ]
},
{
 "id": 3,
 "title": "Cloud",
 "seeAlso": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Sun"
    }
 ]
},
];
```

After inclusion in the database, a node.js search using

```
db.documents.query(
 q.where(
  q.collection('test films'),
  q.value('title','Sun')
 ).withOptions({categories: 'none'})
)
.result( function(results) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null,2));
});
```

will return both the film titled 'Sun' and the films which have a seeAlso/title property (forgive the xpath syntax) = 'Sun'.

I need to find 1/ films with title = 'Sun' 2/ films with seeAlso/title = 'Sun'.

I tried a container query using q.scope() with no success; I don't find how to scope the root object node (first case) and for the second case,

```
q.where(q.scope(q.property('seeAlso'), q.value('title','Sun')))
```

returns as first result an item which matches all text inside the root object node

```
 {
    "index": 1,
    "uri": "/1.json",
    "path": "fn:doc(\"/1.json\")",
    "score": 137216,
    "confidence": 0.6202662,
    "fitness": 0.6701325,
    "href": "/v1/documents?uri=%2F1.json&database=Documents",
    "mimetype": "application/json",
    "format": "json",
    "matches": [
      {
        "path": "fn:doc(\"/1.json\")/object-node()",
        "match-text": [
          "Sun Rain Cloud"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

which seems crazy.

Any idea about how doing such searches on denormalized json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laurent:

XPaths on JSON are supported by MarkLogic.

In particular, you might consider setting up a path range index to match /title at the root:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_54948

Scoped property matching required either filtering or indexed positions to be accurate. An alternative is to set up another path range index on /seeAlso/title

For the match issue it would be useful to know the MarkLogic version and to see the entire query.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the response; I added a path range index on /title from the admin, tested it was ok using the query console and cts:valid-index-path. But I wasn't able to use it in e.g. q.value(q.pathIndex('/title'),'Sun').
My installed version is the latest 8.0.3.

Comment: I just updated the post with the full query and a simplified json structure.

Comment: And I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "Scoped property matching required either filtering or indexed positions to be accurate." I followed the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573892/marklogicnodejs-api-query-on-attribute-of-a-field

Comment: Try qb.range(qb.pathIndex('/title'), '=', 'Sun') -- a range index does a comparison on a datatyped value where a value query does a search matches on the entire value of a JSON property (including applying stemming for strings); you can index JSON property and XML element value positions with the "element value positions" toggle in the database configuration in the Admin UI; you can use withOptions({search:['filtered']}) to inspect documents and remove false positives (but it is faster if the indexes are sufficiently accurate to make that unnecessary)

Comment: is is also possible to isolate the appropriate title by use of a field and the query on the field.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Both q.where(q.range(q.pathIndex('/title'),'=','Sun')) on a new path index and q.where(q.word(q.field('filmTitle'),'Sun')) on a new field work.

Comment: By the way, I also tried to set "element value positions" to true in the database settings to try q.scope again, but with no success. Only withOptions({search:['filtered']} gave good results.